# using substring to clear the last letter of a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string, substring

I have a textarea with the id display_main.
I need this backspacing function to clear the last letter or number of the text area.
This code below did not work.
Please explain.

```
function backspacing(){ 
    document.getElementById("display_main").substring(0, display_main.length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementById` returns an element. Elements aren’t strings, so it doesn’t make sense to take substrings of them. You’ll need to use its `value` property, which is the text contained in the textarea (and many other input elements):

```
function backspacing() {
    var displayMain = document.getElementById("display_main");
    displayMain.value.substring(0, displayMain.value.length - 1)
}
```

Also, `substring` doesn’t modify the string it’s called on; strings are immutable. It returns a new string, which you need to assign to something:

```
function backspacing() {
    var displayMain = document.getElementById("display_main");
    displayMain.value = displayMain.value.substring(0, displayMain.value.length - 1);
}
```

Comment: displayMain.value = displayMain.value.substring(0, display_main.value.length - 1);

Answer (score 1):

Because you're trying to substring the element, instead of the element's value

```
var element = document.getElementById("display_main");
element.value = element.value.substring(0, element.value.length - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks. but a it should be as value.substring

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
function backspacing(){ 
    var textarea = document.getElementById("display_main");
    textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0, textarea.value.length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

get first text area value and apply substring function.

```
 textAreaValue = document.getElementById("display_main").value
```

then apply substring function on value then again set modify value to textarea.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the last character of the textbox and assign it to itself with this code

```
function backspacing() {
        var textbox = document.getElementById("display_main");
        textbox.value = textbox.value.slice(0,-1) ;
}
```

Or if you have jQuery library loaded you can use :

```
function backspacing() {
        $("#display_main").val($("#display_main").val().slice(0,-1));
}
```

Comment: Why would you load 90kb of code just to use the `val()` function? jQuery is not magic!

Comment: I wouldn't load jQuery library for this. I was just saying that if you have jQuery already loaded you can use it.

Comment: The way you worded "or you can use" makes it sound like you advocate jQuery for a trivial line of code. Make sure you emphasize that or people like me will think you're one of those "moar jQuery plugins" people